# Can I add to Linux's privileged ports?

Tags: networking

Ports under ~1000 are privileged in Linux. That is to say only root can bind them. There are various reasons, amongst them security: You *know* that whatever binds one of these ports had root (or `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` given by root) on the server when it took the port. It's less likely to be something masquerading as your application.

I would like to move SSH up to an obscure port. Doing this is easy enough but there is the possibility that if hacked, something could displace the native OpenSSH with something nastier and that it might cause me further issues.

For those reasons, I would like to designate my high port as privileged, so that only my root-run OpenSSH instance can bind it.

Are there any mechanisms in Linux that allow me to do this?

Comment: Maybe with SELinux (or similar), i.e. opposite of [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/245374/using-selinux-to-force-linux-to-allow-programs-to-bind-to-port-numbers-lower-tha). The 1024 limit is hardcoded in the kernel as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can change the privilege ports, but you can do something similar by using `iptables` to redirect your high port to `ssh` running on port 22.

I've not done it myself, but something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport <high port number> -j REDIRECT --to-ports 22
```

may work.